# How to apply puppet manifests and modules WITHOUT installing Puppet RPM?

Tags: package, puppet, rpm

I would like to create an RPM package that applies a Puppet manifest on a server which does not contain Puppet, Facter and Hiera.
Also, and more importantly, I should be able to apply it WITHOUT being obliged to install neither of these tools (Puppet, Facter, Hiera) on the production server.

So basically, the package should run the following command without installing any of the required packages:

```
puppet apply install.pp --modulepath=./modules --hiera_config=./conf/hiera.yaml
```

How can I proceed to make such a package ? Is it a good idea to extract the 'binary' files the Puppet/Hiera/Facter RPMs to include them in another one ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid installing those packages? You certainly *can* manually extract their contents and include them in your own RPM but then you've effectively just installed the packages only without being able to track it as reliably. If you don't actually install the files into the correct locations they may not even work.

Comment: @EtanReisner the manifests are to be applied in one-shot on my customer production servers and they very reluctant to the idea of installing new packages.

Comment: You can always remove them afterwards. But the files need to exist for them to work. They might need to exist in the correct locations for it all to work. If you are going to put files in system locations **without** using rpm to manage that you are asking for trouble. So your choices, as far as I see it, are to use the official RPMs as-is or to repackage their contents in your RPM. The former means you can uninstall them independently of your manifest/etc.. The latter means you cannot.

Answer (score 2):

Installing the relevant packages and then removing them would be by far the fastest and safest way to do what you wish. Maybe you can convince your customer that the cost in time for any other solution is not worth the money. 
Anyway, if packages are not an option, let's be innovative:

- You do not have to install from packages, you can install puppet via [ruby gems](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_gem.html)
- In the same way, you can use [source tarballs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/install_tarball.html)

Those two options might work, but are not innovative enough.

- What about installing puppet 'locally' on a disk via the gems or the tarballs, and then mounting this disk via nfs?
- While we are here, why not do the same but then mount using sshfs?
- still with the idea of a having first a remote install, you could indeed repackage it via [fpm](https://github.com/jordansissel/fpm) (amazing tool, very strongly recommended). You still end up with a package, but a local one which will not require adding a repository, this might alleviate some of your client concerns.
- building on this, if the issue is with repositories, not packages, you could download all required packages and install them manually

I guess that the summary of this answer is that the value of doing so is negative compared to using what you distribution provides.